# How to edit a maven project

Tags: java, maven

This is how I create my multi-module maven project:

**parent-module**

> mvn archetype:generate
>   archetypeGroupId   :   multimodule-project
>   archetypeArtifactId    :   parent-module

**module-A**

> mvn archetype:generate
>   archetypeGroupId   :   multimodule-project
>   archetypeArtifactId    :   module-A

**parent-module** is the parent of **module-A**

After editing **archetypeArtifactId** from the parent pom

> archetypeArtifactId    :   parent-module-edit

I get the error:

```
Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for multimodule-project:module-A:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin is missing. @ multimodule-project:module-A:[unknown-version], D:\mmvnproject\module-A\pom.xml, line 54, column 12
```

How should I go about properly editing a maven project archetypeArtifactId? Is there a database where these settings are stored, so that one would have to edit them there too, and not only the pom?

**UPDATE**

**parent-module pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>multimodule-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>parent-module</name>

    <modules>
        <module>module-A</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

**module-A pom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>multimodule-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post the generated pom.xml files.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml , and which IDE you are using ? ?

Answer (score 1):

Your module-A pom is wrong you should have the underneath pom to make it works :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>module-A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>multimodule-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

EDIT : Update to add some thoughts because you have corrected your original post.

There is something weird with the archetype you are using. Normally, if it was well conceived you just have to execute mvn archetype:generate once. I think because your archetype is not already a multimodule project what is explained your difficulties to set your workspace correctly with it.

If you can modify your archetype by following this [tutorial](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-multi-module-project.html) for creating a good multi-module archetype, I do think it will be easier to use.

Comment: Sorry @Aurelien. My internet went out just after posting the update which had a simple mistake. I just rectified it.

Comment: Ok but there is a mistake that remains the content of your first artifactId element inside your module-A pom would be "module-A" and not "parent-module".